# Unrecognized attribute 'transactionFlow' when using basicHttpBinding

Tags: asp.net, wcf, .net-3.5

I'm creating an ASP.NET web application that is to communicate with a WCF web service. When executing the asp.net web application, that is, when I'm accessing it through a web browser, i get the following error:

`Unrecognized attribute 'transactionFlow' in web.config`. `TransactionFlow` is indeed an attribute under `basicHttpBinding` in my web.config.

Have anyone experienced the same problem? Or do anyone perhaps have an idea why this attribute is not recognized at the web server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only NetTcpBinding, NetNamedPipeBinding, WSHttpBinding, WSDualHttpBinding, and WSFederationHttpBinding are transaction-aware.

Comment: netMsmqBinding as well, no?

Comment: 'transactionFlow' attribute is not available on netMsmqBinding or netHttpBinding.